# urllib3 HTTPResponse.read() returns empty bytes

Tags: python, urllib3

I'm trying to read a website's content but I get an empty bytes object, `b''`.

```
import urllib3
from urllib3 import PoolManager
urllib3.disable_warnings()
https = PoolManager()

r = https.request('GET', 'https://minemen.club/leaderboards/practice/')

print(r.status)
print(r.read())
```

When I open the URL in a web browser I see the website, and `r.status` is 200 (success).

Why does `r.read()` not return the content?

Comment: I'd skip this line `urllib3.disable_warnings()` and see if you get any useful message.

Comment: There is no warning in this case, but you're right to say that the warnings should not be disabled, especially when things don't go as expected.

Answer (score 9):

What makes you think it is wrong? Try the following, you'll have much more output:

```py
print(r.data)
```

Check [HTTPResponse](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/urllib3.response.html#) to see how to use the `r` object you got.

Comment: The link to HTTPResponse seems to be dead. Can you please update? Thanks

Comment: Updated Link: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/urllib3.response.html#

Answer (score 1):

This is how [`urllib3.response.HTTPResponse.read`](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.response.html#urllib3.response.HTTPResponse.read) is supposed to work.

It is explained for example [here](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/715#issuecomment-146984077) by one of the contributors to urllib3:

> This is about documentation. You cannot use `read()` by default, because
> by default all the content is consumed into `data`. If you want `read()`
> to work, you need to set `preload_content=True` on the call to `urlopen`.
> Want to give that a try?

So you can simply use `r.data`.